# How to use HDFS HA in spark on k8s?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

My environment is CDH5.11 with HDFS HA mode,I submit application use SparkLauncher in my windows PC,when I code like

```
setAppResource("hdfs://ip:port/insertInToSolr.jar")
```

it worked,but when I code like

```
setAppResource("hdfs://hdfsHA_nameservices/insertInToSolr.jar")
```

it does not work.
I have copy my hadoop config to the spark docker image by modify

`$SPARK_HOME/kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/entrypoint.sh` 
When I use `docker run -it IMAGE ID /bin/bash`
to run a CONTAINER, in the CONTAINER I can use spark-shell to read hdfs and hive.

Comment: _"it does not work."_ is **not** very informative. Error message? any attempts to fix?

Comment: _"I have copy my hadoop config"_ >> which XML files did you clone? where did you drop these files? did you set `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` env variable for Spark to adjust its CLASSPATH?

Comment: The error message is "java.net.UnknownHostException: hdfsHA_nameservice".I copy the hdfs-site.xml core-site.xml into the spark docker image and set the HADOOP_CONF_DIR

Comment: And do you see `hdfsHA_nameservice` in any of these files?

Comment: Yes,of course,I set the hdfsHA_nameservice in those files